# fast Linear into sRGB

Tags: c++, srgb

It is good way to convert color from Linear space from 0.0 to 1.0   into sRGB space  from 0 to 255  by using  Lookup table in this manner?
Example, in **Java**:

```
byte[] table;
void initializeTable()
{
    table = new byte[65536];
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
         float Lin = i / (float) (table.length-1);
         if(Lin<=0.0031308f)
            table[i] = (byte)(255*(Lin*12.92f));
         else
            table[i] = (byte)(255*(  (1+0.055f)*Math.pow(Lin,1/2.4f)-0.055f)  );
    }
}

int sRGB(float Linear/*in range 0..1*/) // Will return  0..255 integer sRGB
{
    return 255 & table[(int)( Linear*(table.length-1) )];
}
```

Comment: So are you looking up two bytes or one?

Comment: @2501 that's not a duplicate. the linked question is requesting a linear to linear component conversion. sRGB is not linear.

Comment: I was update a little a Code. ↑↑↑ ↑↑↑

Comment: The problem with tables that big is that don't fit into L1 or L2 cache on ARM devices (or modest x86 devices). The cost of a cache miss is significantly more expensive than ... well maybe not Math::Pow, but definitely more expensive than a sensible approximation. You may want to benchmark to make sure you're really speeding things up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks fine to me. You can probably use a smaller table, in fact.

If I were feeling pedantic, I'd say that your conversion from float to int always makes the value slightly darker. You can improve that by changing line 6:

```
float Lin = (i+0.5) / (float) (table.length-1);
```

or by changing line 16:

```
return 255 & table[(int)( Linear*(table.length-1) + 0.5 )];
```

but not both. Either fix centres the rounding error at zero. However, the rounding error still exists, and it is so small that it's not really worth mentioning, so I think your code is fine.

Comment: Actually, the rounding error is big enough to give visibly different results.